# C-extension in Python - return Py_BuildValue() memory leak problem

Tags: python, c, memory, extension-methods, memory-leaks

I have a huge memory leak problem involving a C-extension I'm developing. In C, I have an array of doubles called `A` and an int variable called `AnotherIntVariable`that I want to pass to Python. Well, in my C-extension module I do the following:

```
int i;  
PyObject *lst = PyList_New(len_A);  
PyObject *num;  
if(!lst)  
   return NULL;  
for(i=0;i<len_A;i++){  
   num=PyFloat_FromDouble(A[i]);  
   if(!num){  
      Py_DECREF(lst);  
      return NuLL;  
   }  
   PyList_SET_ITEM(lst,i,num);  
}  
free(A);  
return Py_BuildValue("Oi",lst,AnotherIntVariable)
```

So in Python i recieve this list and the int like this:

```
Pyt_A,Pyt_int=MyCModule.MyCFunction(...)
```

Where Pyt_A and Pyt_int are the list and the integer I get from my C-extension "`MyCModule`", from the function "`MyCFunction`" that I described earlier.

The problem is that, in Python, I use this `Pyt_A` array (so that's why I use `Py_BuildValue` instead of a simple `return` statement, to do an INCREF in order to save this variable for a moment from the garbage collector) but then I need to dereference it somehow in order to free that allocated memory. The problem is that I use the `MyCFunction` function several times, and this produces a memory leakage because I don't know how to dereference the array that I get in python in order to get rid of it.

I tried just returning the array by doing a `return lst` in the C part of the code instead of the `Py_BuildValue("Oi",lst,AnotherIntVariable)`, but that only results in a Segmentation Fault when I try to use it in python (probably because the garbage collector did his work)...

...what am I missing here? Can anybody help me?

Comment: doesn't del Pyt_A in python DECREF the array and delete it?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't seem to work. I still get this memory leakage I'm talking about.

Comment: Also, you do have a return before Py_BuildValue("Oi",lst,AnotherIntVariable) right?

Comment: Yup, I missed it on the post *editing*

Comment: what is sys.getrefcount(Pyt_A) in python?

Comment: The value of sys.getrefcount(Pyt_A) is 3.

Answer (score 13):

If you look at the documentation for `Py_BuildValue` (http://docs.python.org/3/c-api/arg.html#c.Py_BuildValue) you can see that under the `O` typecode, it says that the reference count of the passed in object is incremented by one (Note: an earlier section in that page describes the `O` typecode for `PyArg_ParseTuple`, which *doesn't* increment the reference count, but also isn't relevant here).

So, after the call to `Py_BuildValue`, the refcount for your list is `2`, but you only want it to be `1`.

Instead of returning the result of `Py_BuildValue` directly, save it to a `PyObject` pointer, decrement the `lst` reference count, then return your result.

You should be checking the result of the `Py_BuildValue` call anyway, since you also need to free `num` in the event that `Py_BuildValue` fails (i.e. returns `NULL`).

Comment: The documentation now says _"The object’s reference count is not increased"_ - so which is it?

Comment: The target link anchor for `Py_BuildValue` changed, so the link was going to the top of the page, which covers the `PyArg_ParseTuple` format codes. I fixed the link, and added a note about the potentially confusing entry.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for clearing it up Ignacio, now it makes so much sense! Finally, the solution was to, instead of returning directly the Py_BuildValue, do:

```
free(A);  
PyObject *MyResult = Py_BuildValue("Oi",lst,AnotherIntVariable);  
Py_DECREF(lst);  
return MyResult
```

It worked like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

There's a simpler solution that what the other answers have been suggesting. Don't rearrange your code to decref after using the `O` format code (which takes a new strong reference to the passed object), just use the `N` format code, which *steals* your reference, avoiding unnecessary reference count manipulation entirely by transferring ownership. The *only* change needed for this is to change:

```c
return Py_BuildValue("Oi",lst,AnotherIntVariable);
```

to:

```c
return Py_BuildValue("Ni",lst,AnotherIntVariable);
//                    ^ only change
```

`Py_BuildValue` is pretty robust too; if it fails for any reason it continues parsing arguments to ensure reference counts are stolen and released appropriately. If the `N` argument (`lst`) is passed as `NULL` (usually because a function returning a new strong reference was called in the argument list and failed, setting an exception) it preserves that exception and returns `NULL` itself so the exception propagates as intended.