# Python C extension - memory leaks

Tags: python, memory-leaks, python-c-api, reference-counting

I'm relatively new to Python and this is my first attempt at writing a C extension.

**Background**
In my Python 3.X project I need to load and parse large binary files (10-100MB) to extract data for further processing. The binary content is organized in frames: headers followed by a variable amount of data. Due to the low performance in Python I decided to go for a C extension to speedup the loading part.

The standalone C code outperforms Python by a factor in between 20x-500x so I am pretty satisfied with it.

The problem: the memory keeps growing when I invoke the function from my C-extension multiple times within the same Python module.

---

**my_c_ext.c**

```c
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/arrayobject.h>
#include "my_c_ext.h"

static unsigned short *X, *Y;

static PyObject* c_load(PyObject* self, PyObject* args)
{
    char *filename;
    if(!PyArg_ParseTuple(args, "s", &filename))
        return NULL;

    PyObject *PyX, *PyY;

    __load(filename); 

    npy_intp dims[1] = {n_events};

    PyX = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_UINT16, X);
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS((PyArrayObject*)PyX, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);

    PyY = PyArray_SimpleNewFromData(1, dims, NPY_UINT16, Y);
    PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS((PyArrayObject*)PyY, NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA);

    PyObject *xy = Py_BuildValue("NN", PyX, PyY);


    return xy;
}

...

//More Python C-extension boilerplate (methods, etc..)

...

void __load(char *) {

    // open file, extract frame header and compute new_size
    X = realloc(X, new_size * sizeof(*X));
    Y = realloc(Y, new_size * sizeof(*Y));

    X[i] = ...
    Y[i] = ...

    return;
}
```

---

**test.py**

```py
import my_c_ext as ce

binary_files = ['file1.bin',...,'fileN.bin']

for f in binary_files:
    x,y = ce.c_load(f)
    del x,y
```

---

Here I am deleting the returned objects in hope of lowering memory usage.

After reading several posts (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5508904/c-extension-in-python-return-py-buildvalue-memory-leak-problem), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28905659/creating-a-numpy-array-in-c-from-an-allocated-array-is-causing-memory-leaks) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27557190/python-c-wrapper-memory-leak)), I am still stuck.

I tried to add/remove the `PyArray_ENABLEFLAGS` setting the `NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA` flag without experiencing any difference. It is not yet clear to me if the `NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA` implies a `free(X)` in C. If I explicitly free the arrays in C, I ran into a `segfault` when trying to load second file in the for loop in `test.py`.

Any idea of what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a memory management disaster. `NPY_ARRAY_OWNDATA` should cause it to call `free` on the data (or at least `PyArray_free` which isn't necessarily the same thing...).

However once this is done you *still* have the global variables `X` and `Y` pointing to a now-invalid area of memory. You then call `realloc` on those invalid pointers. At this point you're well into undefined behaviour and so anything could happen.

---

If it's a global variable then the memory needs to be managed globally, not by Numpy. If the memory is managed by the Numpy array then you need to ensure that you store no other way to access it except through that Numpy array. Anything else is going to cause you problems.

Comment: thanks for your answer. What would be a better design? Should I create the numpy array objects `PyX` and `PyY` inside `c_load()` then get a pointer to their `PyArray_DATA` and have them filled by the `__load()` function?

Comment: @charlie_bronx_ Yes - that's probably what I'd do. It's fairly simple, and keeps the memory management completely contained by Numpy.